# How to get entityName or interface name in SpEL for generic repositories in PreAuthorize

Tags: spring, rest, spring-security, spring-data, crud

I'd like to create a generic security crud repository and annotate each method with preauthorize, however I cannot get how to retrieve entity class name

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface AbstractEntityRepository<T extends AbstractEntity> extends CrudRepository<T, String> {
    @Override
    @PreAuthorize("hasPermission(null, #entityName, 'find');
    Iterable<T> findAll();
}

public interface UserRepository extends AbstractEntityRepository<User> {}
```

in this case, entityName is always null.

```
@Component
@Log
public class CustomPermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator {
    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Serializable targetId, String targetType, Object permission)
        log.fine("type " + targetType); // <- null
        return true;
    }
...
```

Any idea how to get either "User" or "UserRepository" ?

Comment: I managed to code a custom class name resolver but not sure that it's a best approach

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component
public class ClassTypeResolver {
    public static String resolve(Object object) {
        if (AopUtils.isJdkDynamicProxy(object)) {
            try {
                return ((SimpleJpaRepository) ((Advised)object).getTargetSource().getTarget()).getDomainClass().getCanonicalName();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            return ((SimpleJpaRepository) object).getDomainClass().getCanonicalName();
        }
    }
}
```